# Change Image Source from Div with onmouseover

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the image source from the containing div? The images are dynamic and pulled from the database.

```
v = $"<div onmouseover=\"document.navIcon.src='/Images/White/{reader[2]}';\" 
      onmouseout=\"document.navIcon.src='/Images/{reader[2]}';\">
<img name=\"navIcon\" src=\"Images/{reader[2]}\"><br>{reader[1]}</div>";
```

That was my thoughts on how to do it but it doesn't appear to work as expected. I was able to get it to work when I put the onmouseover portion in the < img > however, I want it to change anywhere in the div, like over the reader[1] text, not just directly over the image.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just grabbed some images off google images. You can use `this` to refer to the current element.

```html
<img 
     src='https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/images/smilies/50.gif'
     onmouseover='this.src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YrmTHhfMtFU/VJNbpDMHzgI/AAAAAAAAH8c/g3dJ1Q-QTrc/s1600/smile.png"'
     onmouseout='this.src="https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/images/smilies/50.gif"'
     />
```

---

Edit..

This will change the image when you hover on anything with a "hoverme" class name.

```js
(function() {
  var img1 = "https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/images/smilies/50.gif";
  var img2 = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YrmTHhfMtFU/VJNbpDMHzgI/AAAAAAAAH8c/g3dJ1Q-QTrc/s1600/smile.png";
  var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
  myimg.src = img1;
  var hoverables = document.getElementsByClassName('hoverme');
  for (var i = hoverables.length; i--;) {
    hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hoverMe, false);
    hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseout", unhoverMe, false);
  }

  function hoverMe() {
    myimg.src = img2;
  }

  function unhoverMe() {
    myimg.src = img1;
  }
})();
```

```html
<img class='hoverme' id='myimg' />

<p class='hoverme'>poooooooop</p>

<div class='hoverme'>This si a diiiiivvvvv</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will work only when hovering exactly over the image. I want it to work when hovering over the text below it also. Which is why I thought the div would be the best place to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish that is to use CSS.

**HTML**

```
<img id="NavIcon">
```

**CSS**

```
#Navicon {
  background-image: url(image1.jpg);
}
#NavIcon:hover {
  background-image: url(image2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: The problem is the images are dynamic. They are pulled from the database. I haven't researched it but what I know of CSS I wouldn't be able to use that. Correct?

Comment: this method does not account for image size either

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. The good news is my images are properly sized ha. But this method definitely wont help with dynamic images.

Comment: This  approach works only with images with a known size.
If you know the image size simple add a line too you CSS:
`background-size: XXpx YYpx;`

Generally speaking using a visual feedback with an image of different size from the original is not the best approach because it will generate an unpleasant feedback with some flickering of the page.