# Changing Image SRC when hover div with different parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have a product card that I would like to be able to change the main image src of when the user hovers over a 'colour swatch' however, I'm finding this difficult using the answer from here: [Change Image Source from Div with onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452438/change-image-source-from-div-with-onmouseover).

My current code is as follows:

```js
(function() {
  var img1 = "https://picsum.photos/300";
  var img2 = "https://picsum.photos/300";
  var myimg = document.getElementById('img');
  myimg.src = img1;
  var hoverables = document.getElementsByClassName('hoverme');
  for (var i = hoverables.length; i--;) {
    hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hoverMe, false);
    hoverables[i].addEventListener("mouseout", unhoverMe, false);
  }

  function hoverMe() {
    myimg.src = img2;
  }

  function unhoverMe() {
    myimg.src = img1;
  }
})();
```

```css
.product-card{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

    border-radius: 25px;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
.card-body{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%; 

    text-align: left;

    position: relative;}
.card-image{
    max-width:350px;
    max-height:350px;
    padding: 10px;}
.card-sidebar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;

    display: flex;
        align-items: center;

    position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;

    border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;

    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);  
    backdrop-filter: blur(2.5px);}
.swatch-contain{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;}
.swatch{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;

    background-color: aqua;

    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;                
        border-radius: 100%;

    margin: 5px;}
.swatch.black{
    background-color: black;}
.card-foot{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

    border-top: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos300" alt="Aqua Evo22 Backpack" class="card-image" id="img">
        <div class="card-sidebar">
            <div class="swatch-contain">
                <div class="swatch black hoverme" id=""></div>
                <div class="swatch" id=""></div>
                <div class="swatch" id=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card-foot">
        <p></p>
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to have this function for multiple 'swatches' on over around 100 products so I need a solution that is a minimal and easily replicable as possible. what I currently have doesn't function as expected and is very long to keep copying to replace for each product I'll list.

Comment: You write it is very long to keep copying and replace every product.. why not have the things that are different as variables to functions? That way you don't have to fix your code in all places, but just one.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, can you help me with acheiving this? I'm very new to JS

Comment: Well if you're new to JS, why not work through a couple tutorials? You can also just google any question that comes to your mind - someone else in the world certainly had similar thoughts and ideas when learning JavaScript. *how do i work with function parameters in javascript*.. you'll find tutorials and documentation. I don't have time for a private teaching session, I'm sorry.